# Coq: Is there any way avoiding case analysis on sort Set?

Tags: coq

I am trying to construct the reals by using Cauchy sequences of rationals.

```
(* Some Definitions:
   <Q, >Q, <=Q, >=Q: the order in rational
   Q0: the zero as a rational number
   -Q: the subtractions b/w rationals
   Q_abs: the abs value of a rational *)

Definition Cauchy (a: nat -> rational): Prop :=
forall (epsilon: rational), epsilon >Q Q0 ->
  exists (N: nat), forall (n m: nat), n > N -> m > N -> Q_abs (a n -Q a m) <Q epsilon.

Definition real: Set := {r: nat -> rational | Cauchy r}.

Definition R_ne_0 (a: nat -> rational): Prop :=
  exists epsilon: rational, (
    epsilon >Q Q0 /\
    forall N: nat, exists n: nat, (n > N /\ Q_abs (a n) >=Q epsilon)
  ).

Definition R_nonzero: Set := {a : real | R_ne_0 (proj1_sig a)}.
```

However, I cannot `destruct` existence statement in `R_ne_0` since it requires the case analysis on `Set`:

```
Definition R_recip (a: R_nonzero): R_nonzero. (* r |-> 1/r *)
  destruct a as [[a c] n].
  unfold R_ne_0 in n. 
  destruct n.   (* !!!ERROR!!! *)
```

Is there any way to define such a reciprocal using an appropriate definition of `R_nonzero` (in constructive mathematics)? Or, is there any way to avoid (or ignore) such an error as in usual math?

I know that in mathcomp the reals are constructed as an Archimedean field, and I wonder whether there is a possible method to define with Cauchy sequences.

Comment: I haven't read it but have you checked [Constructive Reals in Coq: Axioms and Categoricity](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=646540.696040)?  They write *The construction of the reals is done in the 'classical way': first the rational numbers are built and they are shown to be a (constructive) ordered field and then the constructive real numbers are introduced as the usual Cauchy completion of the rational numbers.*